# Call event in dispatchtimer after every one minute interval

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dispatchertimer

I created a dispatcher timer with one minute interval,

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();//creation of dispatchtimer

private void btnstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
}
```

When button click the timer start and I created event in it.Every one minute interval it will call the event.

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dispatcherTimer.Interval == TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    {
        //...
        //...
    }
}
```

But, My problem is when I click start button it go to event (dispatcherTimer_Tick) after 60 seconds it need to go for that event and after every 1minute interval it will call that event it's working correctly. Initially when I click start button it suddenly call that event but I want **after 60seconds (ie after 1 minute)** need to call that dispatcherTimer_Tick event.

Comment: Unrelated to your bug, you also don't need to check dispatcherTimer.Interval's value in your event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your code doing:

```
//...
dispatcherTimer.Start();
dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
//...
```

instead of:

```
//...
dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
//...
```

Set the `dispatcherTimer.Interval` before calling `Start()`.